# Sum every nth cell in a row infinitely

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

I am making a spreadsheet for my football (or soccer) team, and tracking how much each player has paid and whether they're in credit/debt so I'm calculating the balance in Sheet1 per game and then in Sheet2 calculating the total balance.

The formula I am trying to do is, in Sheet2 trying to `SUM` each value under the "Balance" column for (every 3 cells) for Aidan together to get the total balance.

At the moment I am just doing the following but need it to accommodate an infinite amount of columns (fixtures) and be scalable because currently, this is not.

```
=SUM(Sheet1!D3, Sheet1!G3)
```

[image: Google Sheets Example]
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `FILTER` of `MOD` in `SUM` like:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:2, MOD(COLUMN(B2:2)+2, 3)=0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: For some reason, this effects the row below Aidan as well. E.g. Alex is shown as owing the same balance as Aidan even though Alex has different values

Comment: also make sure that all cells are formatted as numbers not as plain text - or instead of `SUM` use `SUMPRODUCT` which is able to sum plain text

Answer (score 1):

Since the goal is to sum all values from columns with header "Balance", you could also do this:

```
=sumproduct(Sheet1!$B$2:$J$2="Balance",Sheet1!B3:J3)
```

That way you don't have to worry about the index of those columns, should you ever decide to add more columns to your sheet.